Which NVML API call do I use to set the SM clock of an NVIDIA GPU?
I'm trying to use NVML myself, rather than nvidia-smi, to set the SM clocks of my GPU. I have no problem getting the currentl clock rate with nvmlDeviceGetClockInfo, but - I can't figure out how to set it. There's nvmlDeviceSetGpuLockedClocks(), but that's not it (i.e. when I call it, and query again, I get the same frequency as before I made the call). And the other device commands don't seem like they're what I need.
So, which API call is it? Or - could it be that this isn't supported?
